# How to check if (small) aircraft's radio is working properly?

Tags: radio-communications, cessna-172, radio, lost-communications

Is there a standard way to test/check aircraft's radio without calling anybody (Ground/Tower) to see if it is receiving and transmitting?

Is there a way to check aircraft radio with your own handheld radio on the ground before takeoff? I am referring to small aircraft type like Cessna 172.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to tune to an ATIS/AWOS frequency and make sure you can receive clearly. Many radios also have a way to override the automatic squelch to make sure you can adjust your receive volume correctly. Something like this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LWpnGjQCis&t=5m0s

As far as checking if you can Transmit, its kind of hard since you need someone to respond to you. Its pretty common to hear pilots on tower/ground frequencies asking for a mic check. Not sure if this is standard phraseology but it gets the point across

Comment: How do you check if you are transmitting fine?

Comment: Why would you not want to contact ground/tower? You could also use a hand-held radio and tune to an unused frequency...

Comment: I agree with Ron. Why not contact ground/Tower? If you're at a controlled field, you're required to talk to them anyway if you actually want to go somewhere.

Comment: If you are going to use a handheld, it’s best to use the Unicom frequency for the airport. That’s what it is for. Or if it is busy, use the air-to-air frequency reserved for fixed-wing aircraft—122.75 (in the US).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some things you can do, there are probably more. I'm assuming you're mainly interested in checking COM, not NAV.

**Controlled airport**

Check if you can hear the ATIS, Ground or Tower; if you can, then at least you know you can receive. But you might as well just call Ground immediately and ask for a radio check. The correct phraseology in the US (see [the Pilot/Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/)) is "how do you hear me?":

> Bowman Ground, N12345, radio check please. How do you hear me?

**Uncontrolled airport**

Listen to the AWOS, if there is one, to determine if you can receive. Ask UNICOM or another aircraft to give you a radio check. If none of those options are available then you can use a handheld airband transceiver to test. Tune it to the frequency you're listening on and click transmit a few times, as if you're turning on pilot-controlled lights (PCL). If you hear the clicks in your headset, you can receive. To test transmission, do the opposite: click the transmit button on the yoke and listen on the handheld.

**Airborne**

You could call Approach, Center or FSS; try activating the nearest PCL (works best at night); tune and identify a navaid (that doesn't verify COM works, but at least you know something's working); listen to 121.5 ([in the US, you should be doing that anyway](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/us_restrictions/fdc_notams/pdf/FDC%20NOTAMS%204-4386%20and%204-0811.pdf)) because there's usually some bored pilot asking for sports scores on it and some other equally bored pilot yelling at him to "stop talking on [guard!](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/887/62)".

**Troubleshooting**

As always, if you have any problems with transmitting or receiving do some basic troubleshooting first: check you have the correct radio selected; check you have the correct frequency; check the volume controls on your headset and/or panel; turn the squelch up/down/off; check your headset is plugged in correctly; if you have a right-seat passenger, see if they can hear/transmit; and anything else you can think of.

Comment: Clicking can also confirm transmission with pilot controlled lighting or when activating a SuperAWOS.

Comment: the link to correct phraseology is gone

Comment: @vitaly Thanks, the FAA has broken its links yet again.

Comment: @JWalters not sure how likely such issues are, but that wouldn't work to find problems where your PTT is working but audio isn't and your radio only transmits a carrier.

Answer (score 0):

Just call clearance or ground or tower or CTAF and ask "Radio Check".  They will acknowledge you if they hear you.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that without calling ground or tower.