# Why (and when) did people start meowing on guard frequency?

Tags: aviation-history, radio-communications

*meow*

Some love it, some hate it, but we've all heard it - that's right, pilots meowing on guard frequency (121.5).

**When did it start? Does (or did) it represent something?**

Does ATC ever do it?

Comment: Don't know if that is better or worse than "guuuuuaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrddddddddddd"...

Comment: ATC comms are recorded *at the individual control position*. The tapes are occasionally pulled for random auditing. Unlike a lot of other decisions a controller could make, meowing on guard isn't really defensible...

Comment: @RonBeyer - Yes, but we know when that originated - October 22, 2105:  https://youtu.be/YoZE0nE60sk?t=232

Comment: 2105? Were they time travelers? 

Comment: To be followed by "Who dat?", "Who dat who say who dat?"...

Comment: We've all heard it?  Not so.  Indeed, I don't really know what you mean by "on guard".

Comment: @james, you are familiar with the "guard frequency" 121.5, I hope? It is common for pilots to make a transmission **on guard** unintentionally, upon which they will receive the reply "ON GUARD" from a multitude of airline pilots. Or, if they're unlucky, a pilot impersonate whoever the first guy tried to contact. Usually this happens to airline pilots but GA folks may also mistake guard for CTAF, or so I gather from the responses I overhear at my facility. When I transmit on guard, I will say "N12345, Podunk Approach *on guard*," and so will other pilots if they are using guard intentionally.

Comment: This problem seems to be specific to CONUS (which may also be a clue toward its origins), so not everyone will have heard it.

Comment: @randomhead: I've never seen 121.5 called "guard frequency", it's always been emergency or distress frequency.

Comment: @jamesqf https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/887/31936

Comment: Do I look like a cat to you boy? Am I jumpin' around all nimbly bimbly from tree to tree? Am I drinking milk from a saucer? **DO YOU SEE ME EATING MICE?**

Comment: https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2017/july/pilot/turbine-on-guard

Comment: https://youtu.be/eMDknmovgP4?t=265

Comment: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3179/42636 point #11

Answer (score 9):

“Meow” is a reference to a well known movie trope from the US mindless 2001 comedy from the improvisational comedy troupe, Broken Lizard Production, called Super Troopers. In the film, the main characters are Vermont State Highway Patrol law enforcement officers who play games and pranks to break up the monotony of patrolling a very rural area. The same trope is repeated in the 2018 sequel, Super Troopers 2.

After the movie premiered, law enforcement officers would often mimic the characters in the movie amongst themselves. It is extremely rare that a police officer would do this with the general public. It would be a matter of professionalism.

I would hazard a guess that ATC controllers conduct themselves according to a similar professional standard and decorum. Any utterance of “meow” on frequency is more likely to come from a General Aviation pilot.

[The Cat Game](https://youtu.be/1rlSjdnAKY4)

Comment: I would +1 for the origin if you had stopped there, but the article linked by @DeltaLima suggests it is airline rather than GA pilots.

Comment: I postulate that the ATC includes, just as any cohort, a wide range of personal traits. There are asshats among them too.